# RouteValues.TryGetValue gives "Local variable 'X' might not be initialized before accessing" error even if the result is true?

Tags: c#, trygetvalue, routevalues

```
if (!this._contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.RouteValues.TryGetValue("requiredId", out 
var idRouteParam) ?? true)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

var id = (int)idRouteParam;
```

I figured by the time it got to the cast everything would work but I keep getting this compiler error "Local variable 'idRouteParam' might not be initialized before accessing" and cant figure out why

Comment: I believe you must define the variable `int idRouteParam = 0;` before if condition, stop at if condition while debug and see if `RouteValues has this variable and value in it.

Comment: RouteValueDictionary implements `IDictionary<string,object>`. From the compiler point of view it can contain tuple `{ "requiredId", null}`. In this case `TryGetValue("requiredId", out 
var idRouteParam)` will place null into the idRouteParam and return true. 
I don't remember if it is feasible to make such http request in reality, but it is definitelly feasible to pass string into it. In this case you'll have a runtime while converting string to int.

Comment: @sairfan he won't be able to use `TryGetValue` in this case.

Comment: By the way. In code variable is named as `idRouteParam` in question it is named `groupRouteParam` is the code relevant to the question?

Comment: Sorry yes idRouteparam and groupRouteParam are the same variable, i changed it to make it easier to understand but forgot to change it in the error message

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that this is a limitation of definite assignment analysis in the compiler, however only minor adjustment is required to get it to compile, here are a couple of options you could choose from:

Compare with Boolean:

```cs
if (this._contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.RouteValues.TryGetValue("requiredId", out var idRouteParam) != true)
    return Task.CompletedTask;

var id = (int)idRouteParam;
```

Bracket to perform the null-coalesce *before* the `!`:

```cs
if (!(this._contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.RouteValues.TryGetValue("requiredId", out var idRouteParam) ?? false))
    return Task.CompletedTask;

var id = (int)idRouteParam;
```

With either of the above changes the compiler is able to determine that `idRouteParam` is always assigned before use.

Comment: Neither worked unfortunately

Comment: @Mufasatheking - you need to be more specific (show the code you tried and the error you got), both of the examples in my answer compiled without error in my testing.

Comment: Hi, it worked after updating my IDE and restarting my computer. Very strange error

Answer (score 0):

Started working after updating my IDE and restarting my computer. Very strange error.